# Finding differents set of generators of a group given an initial set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a non abelian finite group $G$ which is generated by the irredundant set $S=\{g_1,g_2,\cdots, g_n\}$. How can we find other irredundant sets of generators of $G$ using $S$?
By irredundant sets of generators I mean generators sets in which none element can be expressed as a product of the others.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But If I replace for example $g_1$ by $g_1g_2$ and all the other $g_i$ by $g_ig_1$ resulting in $\{g_1g_2, g_2g_1, \cdots , g_ng_1\}$, what does guarantee that it is a set of irredondant generator?

Comment: Ok! I see. So suppose we have got the new generator set $\{g_1g_2,g_2,g_3, \cdots, g_n\} $. It is clear that it generates $G$. Do you have any Idea on how to show that  element $g_1g_2$ cannot be generated using the others?

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete my comments since replacing $g_i$ with $g_i g_j$ for $j\neq i$ might yield a non-minimal generating set. For example $S=\{3,4\}$ is an irredundant generating set for $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, while $S=\{3,1\}$ ($1=4+3$) is not.

Comment: Is the set $g_1,...,g_n$ already irredundant?

Comment: Yes. $S=\{g_1,g_2,\cdots, g_n\}$ is irredundant. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Take any automorphism (or [anti-automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism)) $\phi$ of your group. Then $\phi(g_1),...,\phi(g_n)$ is a generator too.

**Example**. $\phi(g)=g^{-1}$, or $\phi(g)=h^{-1}gh$ for some $h\in G$.

Less generic examples might depend on the generated group. There might be not much left to do if $G$ is the free group (but I am not sure here).

Comment: Does the new set is guarantee to be different from the initial one with the automorphism $\phi(g)=hg$? how to choose element $h$?

Comment: $g\mapsto hg$ is not a homomorphism when $h$ is different from the identity.

Comment: @Christoph Right, I mixed something up. But $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ should work.

Comment: It works, but is also not a homomorphism in general, since $(gh)^{-1}= h^{-1} g^{-1}$ might be different from $g^{-1} h^{-1}$. It is an [anti-automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism), which should be fine as well.

Comment: @Christoph OP said he talks about abelian groups. Otherwise I would have had the idea $g\mapsto h^{-1}gh$. But yeah, anti-automorphisms should be find too.

Comment: No, OP stated "non abelian". Conjugation is indeed always an automorphism.

Comment: @Christoph Oh, my mistake. Sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: If I consider the automorphism $g \to h^{-1} g h$, how can I choose $h$ in order to have a different set of generator? I ask this because if for instance $h$ belongs to the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ this automorphism is the identity.

Comment: @KTR I cannot give you any general rule, since a good strategy might highly depend on the group $G$. Just don't choose a $h\in Z(G)$. Do you have any specific $G$ in mind? You could choose a $h$ so that $h^{-1}g_1h\not\in\{g_1,...,g_n\}$, but I cannot say you how to find one.

Comment: Ok! I am currently working with the subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$ but it could change later.

Comment: @KTR Then the center is $\{\mathrm{id}\}$ anyway for $n\ge 3$. ;)

Comment: I am not working with the entire group $S_n$ but with some of  its subgroups. If I consider the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $\{(1,2); (3,4)\}$ it seems that the centre is not restricted to $\{id\}$. unless I am missing somethig.

Comment: @KTR You might be right. My comment only applies to all of $S^n$. But since *all* (finite) groups are subgroups of some $S_n$, this only states that you are working with finite groups, which is pretty general.